# CSS Animation on SVG group

Tags: css, svg

Unlike the question I was referred to here, i am trying to get the animation effect with CSS only as I apply it with JS. I am happy to achieve the same thing with a animated filter but I do not know how.

Why is my CSS animation not working on the SVG group? It does work if I apply it to the SVG itself. How do I animate a group within the SVG with CSS per the example here. [FIDDLE here too.](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/strdyy77/2/)

```
.pulse {
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    filter: brightness(1);
    filter: contrast(1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(1);
  }
  50% {
    filter: brightness(0.1);
    filter: contrast(0.1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.1);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(0.1);
  }
  100% {
    filter: brightness(1);
    filter: contrast(1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to use animations on svg elements, then please check https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/ . It may help you

Comment: Hi @Ovidiu Unguru thanks for the link. Already read through it and thought it is more than what I am trying to achieve. I have other classes applied to the `g` element so I do not understand why this one does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animating an SVG Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872057/animating-an-svg-group)

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work on `g` element, though. Another approach would still be CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801538/svg-animation-g-element

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you testing in?  Not all browsers support CSS filters on SVG elements.  By that I mean SVG child elements here.

Firefox does, but I think it might be the only one.

A filter applied to a root `<svg>` element, that is inlined, will work in Chrome, because that is effectively being treated as an HTML element.

http://jsfiddle.net/strdyy77/9/

To filter a `<g>` element, you would need to use an SVG `<filter>`, but the values of those filter elements can't be animated with CSS.